# Ant sshexec task called from gradle doesn't show output

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I want to use Apache ant `sshexec` task in my gradle custom task. The problem is that this task doesn't work (output is not shown in console and sshexec action is not executed). This is how I use it:

```
configurations {
    sshexecAntTask
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    sshexecAntTask 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.7.0'
}

// ----------------------------------------------------

import java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException;
import java.nio.file.Files

class MyCustomTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    def build() {
        String command = ""
        command = 'cmd.exe /C mdir C:\\aadd'
        runSshCommand(command)
    }

    private void runSshCommand(String command) {
        String host = "host"
        String username = "username"
        String password = "password"

        ant.taskdef(name: 'sshexec', classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec', classpath: project.configurations.sshexecAntTask.asPath)
        // this command is not executed; why?
        ant.sshexec(host: host, username: username, password: password, command: command, trust: 'true', failonerror: 'true')
    }

}
```

**[EDIT]**
I've tested sshexec and those are my results:

1. The command `cmd.exe /C echo test > C:\testresult.txt` started from ant works correctly and output is returned to file.
2. The command `cmd.exe /C echo test > C:\testresult.txt` started from gradle works correctly and output is returned to file. Great!
3. The command `cmd.exe /C echo test` started from ant works correctly and output is returned to stdout. **!**
4. The command `cmd.exe /C echo test` started from gradle works correctly but output is not returned to stdout. **!**
5. The command `cmd.exe /C mkdir C:\\\\Inetpub\\\\ftproot\\\\temp\\\\jakisnowykatalog` started from ant works correctly and directory is created (I need to use `\\\\` as path separator because `\\`, `\`, `/` doesn't work)
6. The command `cmd.exe /C mkdir C:\\\\Inetpub\\\\ftproot\\\\temp\\\\jakisnowykatalog` started from gradle doesn't work and directory is not created.

I should add that I want to connect with windows ssh server (not unix/mac) but I've also tested those commands with mac shh without success. Please help!

**[Another edit]**
I've created groovy test code which uses jsch library to execute command and it works. I still don't know why ant task doesn't work.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*
import java.util.Properties;

private void jschTest() {
    Session session = null
    Channel channel = null
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch()
        session = jsch.getSession("host", "login", 22)
        session.setPassword("password")
        Properties config = new Properties()
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
        session.setConfig(config)
        session.connect()

        String command = "cmd.exe /C mkdir C:\\gradledir"
        channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.connect()
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        println e.getMessage()
    }
    finally {
        if (session!=null) {
            session.disconnect()
        }
        if (channel!=null) {
            channel.disconnect()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you declare a task of type MyCustomTask and execute it correctly, I see no reason why the Ant task wouldn't get executed. The problem is more likely elsewhere (e.g. wrong configuration of the Ant task).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. I'm sure that ant works correctly because I use it every day.